# What is the font used in the Thunderbirds 2004 movie?

Tags: font-identification

I've wanted to know this for quite a long time and I've finally decided to ask - does *anyone* know the name of the font (or a very similar font) that is used in the Thunderbirds movie (2004).  I've included an image below.  Thanks

[image: Thunderbirds movie font]

Comment: It's sort of like 'Over there', but not quite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is close to [SOFACHROME](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/sofachrome/) with T and S customisation -

[image]